# How to increase the padding of a MSChart Datapoint label

Tags: c#, .net, label, padding, mschart

I created a chart control displaying the datapoints values as labels. How can I increase the distance between text and label border (padding) for this label (actually for all labels).

First I considered using SmartLabelStyle property of Series class, but I think this property deals with the relation between each label to another instead of their appearance.

[image: MS Chart]

the DataPoints themselves obviously do not provide any options to handle the padding.

maybe I can work with the Font property somehow?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can do without the border you have, you can do this with a DataPoint point:

```
point.LabelBorderWidth = 7;
point.LabelBorderColor = point.LabelBackColor;
```